# UIImagePickerController preview size not the same as the live size

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

My app is using `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo with a photoframe/overlay.  After I take the picture the preview image shows with a black bar below it and above the camera controls toolbar.  I realize this is because the image is being scaled to the correct 4:3 camera aspect ratio, but I wonder if there is a way to control this and the make it fullscreen, aside from the camera controls toolbar.  The problem is that this is causing my photoframe to no longer be aligned properly, as the "pre-preview" view size was the size of the screen minus the camera controls toolbar.

Failing that, I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a good custom UIImagePickerController I could use in place to the standard one so that I don't have to do my own from scratch.  I'm sure there are plenty of them out there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by setting the `cameraViewTransform` property of the `UIImagePickerController` object.  For example

```
  cameraController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(cameraController.cameraViewTransform, 1, yScale);
```

I'm not necessarily convinced this is the best solution, but it seems to do the trick.

Comment: This not works for me.

Comment: This was back in 2013, many versions of iOS ago.  I'm sure things have changed since then.